# PowerBI api powerbi.js error on firefox

Tags: powerbi

I have a product on Microsoft store (PowerBI Tiles), that use the api powerbi.js from Microsoft to get visuals from logged-in user.

When I try to open the application using PowerPoint online on Firefox, we got some problems.

**"The character encoding of the plain text document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the file needs to be declared in the transfer protocol or file needs to use a byte order mark as an encoding signature."**

My team try to solve the problem on our side, but we detect that the problems doesn't come from our code, but from powerbi.js (Microsoft code). Even the demos from Microsoft doesn't work on Firefox.

We create two animated gifs reproducing the problem (on our application and also on the demos from Microsoft)

[Microsoft Demos - Running on Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7jdr0.gif)

[PowerBI Tiles - Running on Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9NYt.gif)

Anyone with this kind of problem? Any solution to this problem.

Many thanks.
João